# Yii2: Menu doesn't open an url

Tags: menu, yii2

I am using the [Yii2 Menu widget](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-menu). This is my menu

```
echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
        'label' => 'Products',
        'url' => '/products' // Not working.
        'items' => [
            [
                'label' => 'New Products',
                'url' => '/new-products'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But the URL `/products` doesn't work when the user click Products, then the menu must be open (it works) and also open the URL **`/products`** (it doesn't work).

Comment: umm... you want to open the menu dropdown and at the same time it should go to the url for the `Products` label i.e `/products`, isnt it happening already with your code? or you want the url to be opened in a new window?

Comment: Open the menu dropdown and at the same time it should go to the url for the Products.

Answer (score 1):

> When specifying the URLs for the menu items you have to specify them
>   in the form of `controller/action` not just as `/controller` even if
>   the default action is used.

This is written on the top as a **`Note`** in the class reference [**`yii-widgets-menu`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-menu) in the very first example code under comments.

So change your url for the `Products` item to

`'url' => '/products/index'`

and also for the `new-products`

`'url' => '/products/new-products'`

Hope it helps.

**Note**: when you specify URLs like **`/controller/action`** it will add it to the baseUrl or domain name removing everything after that.
Like if you have a domain **`http://example.com`** and you are on the page **`http://example.com/contact-us`**. 
It will replace everything after the domain name and add your specified **`http://example.com/controller/action`** and if the menu item URL is provided like **`controller/action`** then clicking it will append it to the existing URL **`http://example.com/contact-us/controller/action`**.

Comment: The url /products/index works (it is defined in my controller) but it doesn't work in the menu entry as a title. If if it inside the item array, it works too.

Comment: i did not get what you are trying to say, what do you mean by doesnt work in the menu entry as a title

Comment: I mean a father item array with a child item array. The father ítem doesn't open the url. The child does.

Comment: @RobySottini have you updated the code according to the suggestion in my answer? can you add the complete code for the menu you have,after the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really expect that clicking "product" item will open submenu and redirect to `/products` page at the same. It does not make any sense, since you will be redirected to different page before you will have a chance to click something in submenu. That's why clicking on "products" only shows submenu dropdown. But this link actually works - try use middle mouse button or disable javascript in your browser.

In your case you should probably define your menu as:

```
echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
        'label' => 'Products',
        'url' => '/products'
        'items' => [
            [
                'label' => 'All Products',
                'url' => '/products'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'New Products',
                'url' => '/new-products'
            ],
        ]
    ]
]);
```

All navigation links should be in submenu.